# Options for systat (iostat/sar) in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, sar, iostat

Going through [cygwin's search](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=iostat), I cannot find linux sysstat apps (e.g., iostat or sar).
Searching the web, I found some old messages of people *unsuccessfully* trying to compile sysstat from source on cygwin.

**Has anyone succeeded in adding sysstat apps to cygwin?**

Environment:
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 t43 1.7.22(0.268/5/3) 2013-07-22 17:06 i686 Cygwin
on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

in cygwin bash under Windows 10+:

```
powershell -Command "& {Get-Counter -Counter '\processor(_total)\% processor time' -Continuous}"
```

Not exactly the same, but gives you access to all Windows performance counters.